Move rows with cell of a certain value from one sheet to another in same workbook
We work on a sheet called Open. Once we have a formula value to show an install is Complete the cells in that row will be moved to the second column in first available row on another sheet. (We put the month number in the first column.)
Sub MoveUsingOneWord()
Dim strSearch As String, EndRw As Long, Rw As Long

' The line below means: come up from the bottom of the sheet to the last empty cell in column A and use that
EndRw = Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).row
strSearch = "Complete"

' The line below means: ignore #N/A errors hopefully
On Error Resume Next

For Rw = 2 To EndRw
    If InStr(Cells(Rw, "A").Value, SrchTerm) Then

        ' The letter A in line below is the first of the rows you want to move
        ' The number 7 in line below is how many cells you want to move, 7 is a test & live will be 32 per row
        With Cells(Rw, "A").Resize(, 7)
            .Copy Sheets("Billed or Cancelled").Cells(Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp)(2)
        .Delete Shift:=xlUp
        End With
        Rw = Rw - 1
    End If
Next Rw
End Sub

Until the invoice number and received date is entered the cell displays the error #N/A hence the resume next entry. Once they are entered it will say Complete.
For the most part it works as I intended, except it moves all cells from all rows.

You not use strSearch and what is SrchTerm ?

When deleting rows you should loop from the bottom up, so deletions don't interfere with your processing.   For Rw = EndRw To 2 Step -1

Thank you both for your time and help with this Black Cat and Tim Williams, I will update the search command and revise the loop as suggested

Move Matching Rows
Sub MoveCompletedInvoices()
       
    ' Define constants.
    Const SRC_SHEET_NAME As String = "Open"
    Const SRC_SEARCH_COLUMN As Long = 1
    Const SRC_SEARCH_STRING As String = "Complete"
    Const DST_SHEET_NAME As String = "Billed or Cancelled"
    Const DST_FIRST_COLUMN As String = "B"
    
    ' Reference the workbook.
    Dim wb As Workbook: Set wb = ThisWorkbook ' workbook containing this code
    
    ' Reference the source worksheet and ranges.
    Dim sws As Worksheet: Set sws = wb.Sheets(SRC_SHEET_NAME)
    Dim srg As Range:
    With sws.Range("A1").CurrentRegion
        If .Rows.Count = 1 Then
            MsgBox "No invoices found!", vbExclamation
            Exit Sub
        End If
        Set srg = .Resize(.Rows.Count - 1).Offset(1) ' whole range (no headers)
    End With
    Dim slrg As Range: Set slrg = srg.Columns(SRC_SEARCH_COLUMN) ' lookup range
    
    ' Declare additional variables.
    Dim surg As Range, scell As Range, r As Long, CellString As String
    
    ' Combine all matching cells into a unioned range.
    For Each scell In slrg.Cells
        CellString = CStr(scell.Value)
        ' is equal
        If StrComp(CellString, SRC_SEARCH_STRING, vbTextCompare) = 0 Then
        ' contains...
        'If InStr(1, CellString, SRC_SEARCH_STRING, vbTextCompare) > 0 Then
        ' begins with...
        'If InStr(1, CellString, SRC_SEARCH_STRING, vbTextCompare) = 1 Then
            If surg Is Nothing Then
                Set surg = scell
            Else
                Set surg = Union(surg, scell)
            End If
        End If
    Next scell
    
    ' Check if no matching cells.
    If surg Is Nothing Then
        MsgBox "No completed invoices found!", vbExclamation
        Exit Sub
    End If
    
    ' Include all columns in the unioned range.
    Set surg = Intersect(surg.EntireRow, srg)
    
    ' Reference the destination last cell
    ' (assumes that the first cell in each source row is populated).
    Dim dws As Worksheet: Set dws = wb.Sheets(DST_SHEET_NAME)
    Dim dcell As Range: Set dcell = dws _
        .Cells(dws.Rows.Count, DST_FIRST_COLUMN).End(xlUp).Offset(1)
    
    ' Copy and delete (move) the unioned range.
    surg.Copy Destination:=dcell
    surg.Delete Shift:=xlShiftUp
    
    ' Inform.
    MsgBox "Completed invoices moved.", vbInformation

End Sub

